# Is there a linear transformation $\psi: Mat_{3x2}(ℝ) \mapsto ℝ_8[x]$ that is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a linear transformation $\psi: Mat_{3x2}(ℝ) \mapsto ℝ_8[x]$ that is surjective?

$Mat_{3x2}(ℝ)$ is the space of real $3$x$2$ matrices.

$ℝ_8[x]$ is the space of all real polynomials up to order $8$.

Could you explain using the Rank-Nullity Theorem?

**Rank-Nullity Theorem:**

For a linear map $\phi: V \to W$ between vector
spaces $V$ and $W$, where $V$ is finite dimensional,

$$\dim \ker \phi + \dim im\phi = \dim V. $$

I understand how to use this. But why must every linear map between these spaces satisfy the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only assumption is that $V$ is finite dimensional. That is definitely the case in your exercise.

Comment: You don't need the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional, when the statement is written as you wrote it.

Comment: As $\phi$ is a linear map, it can be described by a matrix. The dimensions of the kernel and the image depend, if I remember right, only on the rank of the matrix. Perhaps, this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your Rank-Nullity Theorem: take $V=M_{3\times2}(\mathbb R)$, $W=\mathbb R_8[x]$. Then $V$ has dimension $6$ and $W$ has dimension $9$.

If you consider a surjective $\psi:V\to W$, then the dimension of its image is $9$, and so the Rank-Nullity Theorem would imply 
$$
\dim\ker\psi+9=6, 
$$
a contradiction. So no such $\psi$ exists.

Comment: This makes sense, but where's the contradiction?

Comment: It is not possible for the dimension of a vector space to be $-3$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer it directly, without using the theorem. Pick a basis of $P_8$ and choose some preimages of each of these elements. You get a collection in $M_{3\times 2}$ that is larger than its dimension. This means they are linearly dependent. A linear dependence between them gives you, via $\phi$, a linear dependence of the basis you chose in $P_8$, contradiction.

Comment: But who said that $\phi$ is injective?

Comment: @GPerez: If not, then you can restrict to a subspace of $M_{3\times 2}$ where $\phi$ is injective. That makes the argument "even more compelling".

Comment: @GPerez I said choose some preimages. For each $w_i$ in the basis, choose **a** $v_i$ such that $\phi(v_i)=w_i$.

Comment: "This means they are linearly independent."  I think you mean linearly dependent.

Comment: @GPerez: To be a little more precise, choose *one* preimage of each basis vector of $P_8$.  (But the argument is certainly correct and has nothing to do with injectivity of $\varphi$.)  Also: although this answer nicely sidesteps the Rank Nullity Theorem, I'm not completely clear on why we're trying to avoid it, since the OP says he understands how to use it.  This answer *does* of course use that $M_{3 \times 2}$ is finite-dimensional, which is -- if you take the OP at his word -- to be the point that he is missing.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark While the rank-nullity theorem is only an exercise in linear algebra, the idea of passing information about linear dependence or independence between systems of vectors in the domain and target can be used for other problems as well. That is why. What is being used in either proof is *not* the finiteness of the dimension of $M_{3\times2}$ but that its dimension is strictly smaller than that of $P_8$. If they were infinite dimensional this argument would work as well.

Comment: Right, sorry I've been studying a lot and my ideas are jumbled. I got injectivity confused with well-definedness

Comment: "While the rank-nullity theorem is only an exercise in linear algebra, the idea of passing information about linear dependence or independence between systems of vectors in the domain and target can be used for other problems as well." Well, I would say that the Rank-Nullity Theorem is an important theorem in linear algebra which concerns the idea of passing linear independence or dependence between systems of vectors in the domain and target which can be used for other problems as well.  It is really the first isomorphism theorem in this context.  But I don't want to argue about it...

Comment: "What is being used in either proof is not the finiteness of the dimension of $M_{3 \times 2}$ but that its dimension is strictly smaller than that of $P_8$."  Yes, I agree.  (The point of my earlier comment is that the OP seemed to claim understanding of everything except for that.)  The argument would work as well if we had an inequality of dimensions among infinite cardinal numbers, yes.